# How to export qt .dll and import it in c# by pInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, qt

I tried to find some answers but could't find any...

I got dll written in QT (c++) and I need to import it in c# code

I've done it by COM interfaces, but this need registration I would to avoid it, so I read something about pInvoke.

What I got:

MyClass.h

```
class __declspec(dllimport) MyClass : public QObject
{
 public:
     explicit MyClass(QOjbect *parentObject);
     MyClass();
     virtual ~MyClass();

 public:
     Qstring getDeviceName(const QString& deviceNumber);
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
QString MyClass::getDeviceName(const QString& deviceNumber) 
{ 
 some logic code here
}
```

And in my ConsoleApp in c# I need to read this value (copy MyClass.dll into ConsoleApp\bin\Debug directory):

```
class Program{
[dllImport("MyClass.dll")]
 static extern string getDeviceName(string deviceNumber)

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {  
       string name = getDeviceName("13");
     }
}
```

After run build, the exception appear "DllNotFoundException", and I'm sure that this file exists.

Do you have any idea how to fix it? 
Is there any way to marshal variables like enum?

Comment: Have you remembered that you will also have to supply the dll's of QT itself in the right directory?

Comment: and you need all those dll's in the same directory as your exe (ie. in your Debug or Realease build directory). Normally you need to tell your IDE to copy the dll to your exe path. Something like MyClass.dll->properties->copy to build directory or similar. **Edit**: Ah, seems like you have done that.

Comment: If you have it working with COM interop, you should probably stick with that. P/Invoke requires the target dll to export a flat API (C-style). To use it, you're going to have to rewrite a goodly portion of the Qt dll.

Comment: I copied dll into .exe directory too, it doesnt work. @Mark the COM has a lot of problems with registration, thats why I wanted to use it without it